# Solution of symbolic integration in Wolfram-Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integrate

I am trying to get the solution of the following symbolic integral using Wolfram-Mathematica:

```
Integrate[1/(w^2 + l^2 + 2*l*w*Sin[t*w]), w]
```

but it does not return any solutions. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you. I did try Rubi as you suggested but again it would not return any solutions.

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter trigonometric functions (sin, cos), it is often useful to go to the exponential form (see the Help on TrigToExp).

This solves your integral easily:

```
solutionExp = Integrate[TrigToExp[w^2 + l^2 + 2 l w Sin[t w]], w]
```

This solution can be brought back to trigonometric form with ExpToTrig:

```
solutionTrig = ExpToTrig[solutionExp]
```

Comment: Thank you. If you notice, the expression I wanted to integrate is not the same as what you have tried to solve. The one you offered the solution for is the denominator of the original expression I am interested in. When I try the TrigToExp function on the original expression, it does not work.